# How i can get ram type info from my device?

Tags: android

I trying to know ram type of my android device programmatically, but dont know how. Maybe some system files contain this info or something else?

Comment: what do you mean by ram type?

Comment: LPDDR4 for example @MajidAli

Comment: good question, I've been looking for similar lines for screen type (LCD/LED), but haven't found nothing useful...

Comment: ok i was searching for this also when i was working on an app but unable to find any answer just found how to check ram usage or ram memory etc but not type i think we can if we have root access..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38625284/7924565 further just check this for information purpose..

Comment: @MajidAli its not answer,but thx

Comment: @AmirDora. not, i trying to get ram memory type, not size